# Scipy solve_ivp vs odeint

Tags: python, scipy, odeint

I have a large system of differential equations I am trying to solve. I get the same results using `scipy.odeint` and `scipy.solve_ivp`, however the former is ~17 times faster in my case. I read that `solve_ivp` is recommended for initial value problems, but can't find more on why I can't use `odeint` (when it's giving me the same results).

Do I need to use `solve_ivp` when I am getting the same results as from `odeint`? When would I use one vs the other?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using the default `method` in `solve_ivp`.  I see a `LSODA` alternative that may work more like the `odeint`.  The `solve_ivp` recommendation may be based on it providing more method options, and a newer, more systematic interface.  Read, and reread, the docs!

Comment: You are correct. I used the default 'RK45' method. 'LSODA' was much faster, and gave similar results.

Comment: You *can* use `odeint`.  As @hpaulj noted, `solve_ivp` is newer and has more features, but `odeint` still works.  How does the peformance of `solve_ivp` with the 'LSODA' method compare to that of `odeint`?  Note that the default error tolerances used by `odeint` are much smaller than those used by `solve_ivp`.  You might want to adjust these to make an "apples to apples" comparison.