# Scipy integrate: is solve_ivp "always worse" than odeint?

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-integration, odeint

#### Analytical solution for an example ODE

I was testing the difference between these methods by solving the following initial value problem:

```
y'=2*y-t
```

You can solve this analytically by considering that `y(t)` is a linear combination of a homogeneous solution `y_h(t)=c1*exp(2t)` and a particular solution `y_p(t)=t/2+1/4`. The constant `c1` is found by substituting `y(t0)=y0`. The analytical solution is then:

```
y(t)=(y0-t0/2-1/4)*exp(2*(t-t0))+t/2+1/4
```

**Note** that if `y0=0.25` and `t0=0`, this is the same as `y(t)=t/2+1/4`. In this case `y(1)=0.75`.

---

#### Comparison between `solve_ivp` and `odeint`

First `from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp, odeint`.

By writing `odeint(lambda y,t: 2*y-t,[0.25],[0,1])` we get the expected results `y(0)=0.25` and `y(1)=0.75`.

But, by writing `solve_ivp(lambda y,t: 2*y-t,t_span=[0,1],y0=[0.25],t_eval=[0,1])` we get the results `y(0)=0.25` and `y(1)=0.82775742`.

As mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61237298/scipy-solve-ivp-vs-odeint), `solve_ivp` should have the 'LSODA' method and have its tolerances adjusted in order to fairly compare it to `odeint`. By reading the [scipy odeint documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html#scipy.integrate.odeint) we see that the tolerances are around `1.49e-8`.

But `solve_ivp(lambda y,t: 2*y-t,t_span=[0,1],y0=[0.25],t_eval=[0,1],method='LSODA',atol=1.49e-8,rtol=1.49e-8)` still yields `y(0)=0.25`
 and `y(1)=0.82772876`.

And if you try this for greater time spans, the results only get worse with `solve_ivp`, for this particular example.

---

Am I missing something?

Comment: I am stuck on the same question for a different system. `solve_ivp` also gives me worse results than `odeint` even though I'm using the kwargs `method='LSODA',atol=1.49e-8,rtol=1.49e-8` in `solve_ivp` and even though I'm using the correct order of y and t. Did you come across any other insights along the way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to sleep...

According to the [odeint documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html#scipy.integrate.odeint), the function has to be of the type `func(y, t)` (although it does accept `f(t,y)` if you specify it).

And according to the [solve_ivp documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html#scipy.integrate.solve_ivp), the function has to be of the type `func(t, y)`.

Comment: In recent numpy version, the trick is to give `tfirst=True` to `odeint`, this way the interface of the `odeint` and `solve_ivp` are the same.  
`dqdt = lambda t,y: 2*y-t`, `res1 = odeint   (dqdt, y0, t_eval, tfirst=True)` and `res2 = solve_ivp(dqdt, (t_eval[0],t_eval[-1]), y0, method='LSODA', t_eval=t_eval, atol=1.49e-8, rtol=1.49e-8)`. This snippet also make sure the returned evaluation times are the same for both.